# MySQL find date gaps in timeslices

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table VariableValues in which a value is stored together with a `startdate`,`enddate` and `TariffVariableName`.

Another table Variable also has  `start` , `enddate`  and `name`

EndDates are exclusive: so `timeslice` for month `february 2016` would be `2016-02-01 - 2016-03-01`

I want to perform two checks (I prefer two queries)

**One: There may be no gaps within the VariableValues**

**Example:**

```
    VariableValue.Name = name1
    startdate: 2016-02-01 - enddate: 2016-03-01
    startdate: 2016-04-01 - enddate: 2016-12-01
```

> ==> Should give an error as month April is not covered.

**Two: The full period of the Variable should be covered by VariableValues**

```
    Variable.startdate: 2016-01-01 - enddate 2017-01-01
    VariableValue.startdate 2016-01-01 - enddate 2016-06-01
    VariableValue.startdate 2016-06-01 - enddate 2016-11-01
```

> ==> Should give an error as the month November and December is not covered by Values

Any help?

Comment: Please provide us with the code you've tried so far. At it's current state, it looks more like a feature request for us than a coding issue. Since this isn't a free coding service, we need to see what you have tried and where you're stuck, and then we can help you from there.

Comment: My current code is too long by 630 characters. I was trying it with php code, but I prefer the SQL solution as provided below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gaps** detector:

```
CREATE TABLE VariableValues (TariffVariableName CHAR(5), StartDate DATE, EndDate DATE);
INSERT INTO VariableValues (TariffVariableName, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES ('name1', STR_TO_DATE('20160201', '%Y%m%d'), STR_TO_DATE('20160301', '%Y%m%d'));
INSERT INTO VariableValues (TariffVariableName, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES ('name1', STR_TO_DATE('20160401', '%Y%m%d'), STR_TO_DATE('20161201', '%Y%m%d'));

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        next.TariffVariableName,
        (
            SELECT MAX(prev.EndDate)
            FROM VariableValues prev
            WHERE prev.TariffVariableName = next.TariffVariableName
              AND prev.EndDate < next.StartDate
        ) AS StartDate,
        next.StartDate As EndDate
    FROM VariableValues next
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT '*'
        FROM VariableValues overlap
        WHERE overlap.TariffVariableName = next.TariffVariableName
          AND overlap.EndDate >= next.StartDate
          AND overlap.StartDate < next.StartDate
    )
) gap
WHERE gap.StartDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY gap.TariffVariableName, gap.StartDate;
```

The same approach can be used to check interval **Cover**: for each interval from Variable take all overlapping intervals from VariableValues, add two artificial intervals: Variable.StartDate - Variable.StartDate and Variable.EndDate - Variable.EndDate, and run the above Gaps detector.